# preg_match() returning always empty arrays

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am still newbie so maybe it is simple but, I tried lot of things i found here and still cant get it right.

**$patternPopis ='/(?:[^:|\d ])[A-Za-zÀ-ȕ .?+\d]+(?=\n)/i';**

**preg_match($patternPopis, $row, $popis);**

in regexr its working nicely
test strings ($rows) :

po 19. duben 2021 21:29 **Objednávka vytvořena + ?**\n //wanna this

st 21. duben 2021 10:27 name name: **Objednávka automaticky označena jako dohledaná + ?**\n //wanna this

st 21. duben 2021 17:18 name: **Objednávka podána u GLS pod číslem 1004032**\n //wanna this

i tried too preg_match_all()
mb_eregi()
tried to change regex with lookaheads

**dump($popis);
returning []**

thx if you can help <3

Comment: Are you sure there is a newline at the end? Did you try `(?:[^:|\d ])[A-Za-zÀ-ȕ .?+\d]+$`

Comment: Hi, yeah I am using strings that always end like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If your `\n` is a newline, line feed `\xA0` char**, you can use

```php
<?php

$patternPopis ='/[^:|\d ][A-Za-zÀ-ȕ .?+\d]+$/ium';
$row = "po 19. duben 2021 21:29 Objednávka vytvořena + ?\n";
if (preg_match($patternPopis, $row, $popis)){
    echo $popis[0];
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/pmBkC).

*Notes*

- `(?:[^:|\d ])` = `[^:|\d ]`, the non-capturing group is superfluous
- The `u` flag is required as the text contains non-ASCII chars
- `m` flag is advisable since you might want to find matches in a multiline text and the pattern suggested contains `$` (instead of `(?=\n)`)
- `$` with `m` flag matches a line end position, which makes the pattern leaner.

**If the `\n` is a two char combination, a backslash + `n`**, you can use

```php
$patternPopis ='/[^:|\d ][A-Za-zÀ-ȕ .?+\d]+(?=\\\\n)/iu';
$row = 'po 19. duben 2021 21:29 Objednávka vytvořena + ?\n';
if (preg_match($patternPopis, $row, $popis)){
    echo $popis[0];
}
```

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/VfZkQ).

The `(?=\\\\n)` lookahead matches a location immediately followed with `\` and then `n` chars. `m` flag is not necessary here.

Comment: Thank you kind sir <3 first approach is working nicely, second still getting null somehow, but i can make it work with first one easily (y).